# Predictive density via LOOCV

Tags: cross-validation, density-function, prediction-interval, nonparametric-density

I am looking for a way to generate a density prediction (in contrast to a point prediction or a prediction interval) in a multiple regression setting without relying on stringent parametric assumptions.

I have an idea of constructing the density prediction by centering the empirical distribution of the LOOCV prediction errors around an estimate of the conditional mean. (**Update** almost 4 years later: I think a related concept is *conformal prediction*, and I am expanding it from the usual conformal prediction interval to a conformal density.) I have done a simulation of a very simple case (described below), and it worked well.

**Questions:**

1. What are some pitfalls of such an approach? When would such a density prediction fail?
2. Is there a superior approach that does not require much stricter assumptions?

(One drawback I am aware of: the density prediction does not reflect that prediction errors tend to be larger when $X$ is far away from its mean.)

---

The simulation that seemingly worked well:
$$
y=X\beta+\varepsilon
$$
where $\varepsilon \sim N(0,1)$ and $X$ is a sample of a $10$-variate approximately independent $X_i$s each of which is $N(0,1)$. $\beta=(1,\dots,10)^\top$ are some coefficients.

Below is my R code, if anyone is interested. (It is clearly inefficient as it reestimates the model fully in each subset of LOOCV, but a computational time of 5 or 10 minutes was fine with me when I ran it.)

```r
n=1e2 # sample size
k=1e1 # number of regressors
M=1e4 # number of simulation runs

#========== Prediction errors from LOOCV

pred.errs.LOOCV=pred.errs.trueOOS=matrix(NA,nrow=n,ncol=M)

print(paste(Sys.time(),"start of loop")); for(m in 1:M){
 if(m%%100==0) print(paste(Sys.time(),"m =",m))
 #========== In-sample
 # Generate in-sample data
 set.seed(m); epsX=matrix(rnorm(n*(k+1)),nrow=n,ncol=k+1); eps=epsX[,1]; X=epsX[,-1]; y=X%*%c(1:k)+eps
 # LOOCV: estimate models, predict, calculate prediction error
 for(i in 1:n){
  lm1=lm(y[-i]~X[-i,])
  pred.errs.LOOCV[i,m]=y[i]-sum(lm1$coef*c(1,X[i,]))
 }
 #========== Out-of-sample
 # Estimate the model on the full in-sample
 lm1=lm(y~X) # still using in-sample data!
 # Generate out-of-sample data
 set.seed(M+m); epsX=matrix(rnorm(n*(k+1)),nrow=n,ncol=k+1); epsnew=epsX[,1]; Xnew=epsX[,-1]; ynew=Xnew%*%c(1:k)+epsnew
 # Obtain out-of-sample prediction error
 pred.errs.trueOOS[,m]=ynew-cbind(1,Xnew)%*%lm1$coef
}; print(paste(Sys.time(),"end of loop"))

#========== Comparison of distributional properties of LOOCV-based and true OOS prediction errors

pred.errs.LOOCV  =c(pred.errs.LOOCV  )
pred.errs.trueOOS=c(pred.errs.trueOOS)
# Density, etc.:
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 # Kernel densities on top of each other
 plot (density(pred.errs.LOOCV  ))
 lines(density(pred.errs.trueOOS),col="blue")
 # Sorted LOOCV vs. sorted trueOOS plot
 plot(x=sort(pred.errs.LOOCV),y=sort(pred.errs.trueOOS))
 lines(x=c(-10,10),y=c(-10,10))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Some related questions can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-validation+prediction-interval).

Comment: (+1) Have you considered comparing against quantile regression directly? I ran the simulations you attached and indeed they seem quite good but I am uncertain how they relate to your original task of "generating a density prediction". Wouldn't be more relevant to have something akin to a Wasserstein metric?

Comment: @usεr11852saysReinstateMonic, quantile regression is of course an option, perhaps a better one than I have here (though it is computationally more expensive than an efficient single-run implementation of LOOCV). When and how much better must depend on the setup -- I am interested in learning more if you have any thoughts. Then you could post it as an answer. In any case, I am still looking for cases where my approach fails. Otherwise I would think it can be a useful benchmark because of its simplicity and generality.

Comment: I did not use a metric but rather looked at the kernel density visually so that I get a picture of the entire distribution. I though I would stay open to a variety of loss functions, potentially including asymmetric ones.

Comment: A bounty has been wasted on this question. I will wait before offering another one, but if you happen to post an outstanding answer, I will consider awarding the bounty afterwards.